# How can I execute an application installed on the apache debian server through php?

Tags: php, permissions, server, exec

I am using the following code

```
<?php
$output = exec('command line here');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

to run an application installed on the server side. The application should output a file, which should be written on the server.

- When I run the php file, the application runs, except it doesnt create the
  file on the server.
- If I run the command through ssh, the application creates the file
  successfully on the server.

Comment: I am guessing that the user that Apache runs as does not have privileges to run this prog

Comment: if it works you do do it, but not from apache, then it's almost always a permission issue.

Comment: Solved the problem. It was indeed solved after file permissions were updated.